# Chrome keeps shutting down right after launching with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

```py
from selenium import webdriver
class instaBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")
instaBot()
```

Comment: Hello, I have edited your question to add some python code formatting and make it more readable.

Comment: You are just opening a URL and returning. You could try to put a `sleep` after `driver.get` if you just want to verify that the page is being loaded. Besides, don't do that in the constructor, write a method for that.

Comment: Got it guys thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser version and make sure there is no compability issue while launching your chrome browser, you can download  [[Latest Chrome driver from here]](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

```
class bot:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")

    def instagramLogin(self):
        driver = self.driver
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")

        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys("username")
        WebDriverWait( self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys("username")
        WebDriverWait( self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Log In')]"))).click()

        driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = bot()
    bot.instagramLogin()
```

Note:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
```